# Codrops Multi Level Menu - Load html pages not ajax content but keep animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, animation

I am using a multi level menu found on CoDrops at: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/11/17/multi-level-menu/

The problem I am facing is being able to load my menu's individual HTML pages, as content is loaded via ajax.

In my menu, when a link to example.html is clicked, I want this content to be loaded, either via Ajax, or load the file completely independently. What I don't want is to be loading everything via Ajax from 1 file (this will be very messy for me).

If you download the source and put a link in the navigation to go somewhere, you'll see it doesn't do anything.

However when I try and remove some Javascript, I manage to break the animation everytime. (duh ._.)

Is there some legend out there that knows how I can achieve directly linking to an html file (or loading each pages content via ajax from an independent html file) while keeping all the menu's animation in tact?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted "onItemClick: loadDummyData" within the JS and this works - easy problem solved - I am a JS newb.